# Ajax in PHP5 - update drop down list with other drop down list

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to update drop down list with the other drop down list using Ajax. Somehow it is not working. I'm not sure which path is going wrong.

### php file

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function AjaxFunction(cat_id)
    {
    var httpxml;
    try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
        try
                   {
                httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
           catch (e)
                {
             try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
             catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
          }
  }
function stateck() 
    {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {

var myarray=eval(httpxml.responseText);
for(j=document.testform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.testform.subcat.remove(j);
}


for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myarray[i];
optn.value = myarray[i];
document.testform.subcat.options.add(optn);

} 
      }
    }
   var url="dd2.php";
url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
  }
</script>


<title>tresn</title>
</head>


<table width="1021" border="0" style="top:0;left:0; position:fixed">
  <tr>
    <td height="25"><form action='Test3.php?mula=0&amp;akhir=12' method="POST" class="dropdown_button" name="testform" id="form1">
      <strong> 
        Sort By:
        <select name="cat" onchange="AjaxFunction(this.value);" id="SortBy">
          <option value="0">(Short By)</option>
          <?php
$q=mysqli_query($db,"select * from db_prd_category ");
while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
echo "<option value=$n[Cat_Id]>$n[Name]</option>";
}
?>
        </select>
        <select name="subcat">
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class ="small button yellow" name="Filter" id="Filter" style="height:25px" value="Filter" />
        &nbsp; </strong>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>`
```

### Ajax file

```
<?php
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
require "config.php";

$q=mysqli_query($db,"Select * from db_prd_subcategory where Cat_Id='$cat_id' ORDER BY  SubCat_Id ASC");
echo mysqli_error();
$myarray=array();
$str="";

while($n=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
$str=$str . "\"$nt[Name]\"".",";
}

$str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); 
echo "new Array($str)";

?>
```

Comment: 1. reformat your code with proper spacing. 2. use jquery for crossbrowser AJAX. 3. Get rid of SQL injections. 4. Post SQL structure of your category table. 5. Provide minimal reproducible example on phpfiddle. 6. Use JSON as AJAX handler output, not js `eval` + JS code. 7. replace `echo mysqli_error()` with proper DB error logging

Comment: Also you named the Javascript-File as PHP-File and your serverside PHP-File is named as AJAX-File. Use JQuery for AJAX calls as Alexey said that way you don't have to write that complicated JS-AJAX code where bugs are really easy get.